# Bootstrap column disorder on large screen after xs values added

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm optimizing my gallery for mobile resolution, where at `col-sm-4` everything worked perfectly, then I needed to add `col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2`, which made it look the way I wanted for mobile, but it messed up the large screen look. Why do the added `xs` values affect the arrangement of the columns at larger viewports?

```css
#portfolio {
 margin-top:50px;
 padding-bottom:50px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
}

.gallery {
 margin-top:50px;
}

.gallery-item {
 padding:0px;
 border:1px solid white;
 position:relative;
}

.gallery-overlay {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 transition:1s;
}

.gallery-overlay img {
 z-index:-1;
 position:relative;
}

.gallery-overlay:hover {
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0) 45%, rgba(0,0,0,.7)70%);
 transition:1s;
}

.gallery-caption {
 color:white;
 top:75%;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 opacity:0;
 z-index:102;
 transition:1s;
}

.gallery-item:hover .gallery-caption{
 display:block;
 transition:1s;
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="more"></div>
 <div id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Some of Our Jobs as Students</h1>
    <div class="separator"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- gallery starts -->
   <div class="gallery clearfix col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <a href="http://balazs.dk"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500"></a>
       <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">Balazs' Portfolio</h3>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <a href="http://laszlovaszi.com/portfolio"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500"></a>
       <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">Laszlo's portfolio</h3>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-4 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <a href="http://laszlovaszi.com/survey"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="500x500"></a>
       <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">Survey made for Jokula</h3>
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- new row starts -->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <a rel="portfolio" href="photos/office_woman_l.jpg" data-gallery><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="thumbnail"></a>
       <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">office woman</h3>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <a rel="portfolio" href="photos/laptop_l.jpg" data-gallery><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="thumbnail"></a>
       <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">laptop</h3>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-overlay">
       <a rel="portfolio" href="photos/glasses_woman_l.jpg" data-gallery><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" alt="thumbnail"></a>
       <h3 class="gallery-caption text-center">glasses woman</h3>
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- gallery ends -->
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `.col-xs-offset-2 {margin-left: 16.6667%;}` this is creating the problem.. hide it..

Comment: Make the offset `col-xs-offset-4`

Comment: @user6028084, I cannot see any margin-left being set up, how do you mean to hide? 
@MAZux, I've tried your suggestion, but then it aligns the thumbnails in a single column, but I need `col-sm-4`.. Why does the `xs` attribute override the `sm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's beacause the offset you have is the xs-2, since you haven't adjusted that value for larger screens bootstrap will still apply the offset on other resolutions. Try adding a .col-sm-offset-0 which will override your .col-xs-offset-2 for larger screens

Comment: Awesome! Who would have thought that if I set offset in `xs` and set up normal columns in `sm` then the `xs-offset` is gonna remain there? :)

Comment: it's kinda why it has a mobile first design, so you don't clutter things with all the extra classes ^^

Comment: Consider that if you set a class xs-offset, that class will apply until bootstrap encounters a more appropriate class to apply.  In this case, there was no other class to apply.